# Why this flex slider directional nav has no images / empty?

Tags: navigation, flexslider

I am testing this [page](http://goo.gl/1zVRfz)
Flex slider is working nd loading fine.

But why the next / previous button has no any images or looks empty?

It's flex slider 2 .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fixed by moving flexslider `fonts` folder to the css folder where my `flexslider.css` is placed.